# Can't update my system using apt update

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I am unable to Update my system.

```
root@Pi-Hole:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 3, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (74: Bad message)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt` fix the issue?

Comment: Sadly Not, this results in: root@Pi-Hole:~# sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (74: Bad message)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
root@Pi-Hole:~#

Comment: If you are sure there's no running process, that is, if you have killed the process (apt or dpkg) that was running the update, then you can delete the lockfile: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` and then run apt again.